# JSON.stringify is not serialiizing the object

Tags: javascript, json

i am trying to do ajax call by passing serialized json object and assigning it to data property of the ajax call.
but some thing is not proper at assigning serialized object to data property control goes to jquery-2.0.3.min.js file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function AddEmployee() 
    {


        var Product = new Object();
        Product.Name = "kRISH";
        Product.Price = "23";
        Product.Category = "AS";

        $.ajax
        ({
            url: 'http://localhost:62310/api/products',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(Product),
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data){ WriteResponse(data);},
            error: function (x, y, z){ alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);}
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: data: JSON.stringify(Product : Product) ?

Comment: There is something wrong with your syntax. JSON.stringify(Product : Product). It should be something like JSON.stringify(products) where products is a JSON object.

Comment: can you specify tutorial that can gain me knowledge on web api , jquery , json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do

```
var json_text = JSON.stringify(Product, null, 2);

 $.ajax
        ({
            url: 'http://localhost:62310/api/products',
            type: 'POST',
            data: json_text ,
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data){ WriteResponse(data);},
            error: function (x, y, z){ alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);}
        });
```

Comment: Why use pretty printing, when only transmitting to a server?

Comment: can you specify tutorial that can gain me knowledge on web api , jquery , json

Comment: @SunilJadhav : https://developer.mozilla.org is your friend

For JSON , it is https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON
For Jquery , JQuery documentation is good

Comment: Now json string is serialized but when control comes to $.ajax goes to java script file and some internal lines are executed.

Comment: Eh , I donot understand

Comment: In short some error comes but is not shown neither execution halts.  [to harsha]

Answer (score 1):

Either you want to serialize an object with a property `Product`, then you need

```
data: JSON.stringify( {Product : Product} )
```

or you just want to serialize your Product, then you need

```
data: JSON.stringify(Product)
```

btw your object initialization could be rewritten as:

```
var Product = {
  Name : "kRISH",
  Price : "23",
  Category : "AS"
};
```

Comment: please re-check i had made a mistake while posting the question.JSON.stringify(product) also does not executes.it goes to jquery-2.0.3.min.js file

Comment: can you specify tutorial that can gain me knowledge on web api , jquery , json

Comment: @SunilJadhav There should be plenty on the net and you should be able to find them using google. I would recommend to start with the respective [jQuery Docu](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or in general [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JSON).

Answer (score 1):

`Product : Product` is not an object.

You should replace it with an actual object :

```
$.ajax
    ({
        url: 'http://localhost:62310/api/products',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({Product : Product}),
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data){ WriteResponse(data);},
        error: function (x, y, z){ alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);}
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/floo51/x52GX/

Comment: PLEASE RE CHECK i had made a mistake while posting the question.\

Comment: please re-check i had made a mistake while posting the question.